# Which pair of letters is missing from this sequence?

Tags: letter-sequence

LB, GO, HG, KL, ? OE

a) GN
b) NH
c) DL
d) OM

Comment: Considering you've given us four options, is this from a textbook/exam paper? If so, you should ideally mention the source in the question.

Comment: Not just "ideally". We absolutely forbid the posting here of other people's puzzles without suitable acknowledgement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reason I think it could be (b) "NH":

> The five known entries all together only repeats any letter at most once:
>  LBGOHGKLOE -> B E GG H K LL OO
>
>  Adding (a), (c), or (d) would each add an already repeated letter:
>  (a) +GN -> GGG
>  (c) +DL -> LLL
>  (d) +OM -> OOO
>
>  ...while adding (b) doesn't:
>  LBGOHGKLNHOE -> B E GG HH K LL N OO